# privacy concerns in using google doc viewer

Tags: google-app-engine

I am planning to use [Google Doc Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer) for previewing documents before printing.

The servlet code in my application running on GAE  which sends file has user/session validation 
before invoking a fileSend method. But when I point my URL to google doc viewer ,it cannot succeed as user check fails.

I cannot remove this check, if done anyone can invoke my URL to download files.
how can I handle this security concern? is there a way to pass user information  to Google Doc Viewer?
If not are there any alternatives?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying this http call -  http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://myapp/filedownload.action   the response is document(file) opens up in a viwer. How do I authenticate this call?. It is possible to authenticate http://myapp/filedownload.action since I know who is logged in(userId) but when invoked via doc.google how does myapp know who is the user?

Comment: not possible. you cant authenticate a remote user for them, they need to do it. for that you need to share the file with them or make it public.

Comment: is free or comercial Google Docs Viewer?